# FontAwesome doesn't display in Firefox 33

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

here is the code and fontawesome fonts are displaying on chrome but not in mozilla 33.0.what is the mistake i am doing?

```
<head>
    <title>Welcome To Sri Mata Anandamayi Ashram</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Sri Mata Anandamayi Ashram">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- CSS Bootstrap & Custom -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">



    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
        <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: I don't see any font-awesome class in the code.

Comment: Doesn't look like you're using any fontawesome elements, that's probably why

Comment: I've read that Adblock Plus blocks the social media icons from FontAwesome, check it, it could be your problem if the blocked icons are the Twitter logo, te FB logo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use any of font-awesome classes for icons.
With your version of FA here is example:

```
<i class="test fa fa-coffee"></i>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1158kjwf/

Comment: i think there is some browser compatibility issue in this because the code is working on chrome but not in mozilla.

Comment: as i have used font-awesome classes for icons in my css sheets too